# Disable quote rule in Eslint config file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I could only find rules to show errors for a double quote, single quote, or backticks. Couldn't find a rule to fully disable this quote error. I don't want to see an error no matter what quote is being used in a project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two options.
You can add these rules inside `eslintrc.json`

`"avoidEscape": true` allows strings to use single-quotes or double-quotes so long as the string contains a quote that would have to be escaped otherwise

`"allowTemplateLiterals": true` allows strings to use backticks

the reference here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes

Comment: Can you please accept this answer if you like it? Akihil?

Answer (score 9):

Hi You can use this rule in the `.eslintrc.json` file

```
{
...
   "rules": {
      ...
      "avoidEscape": true,
      "allowTemplateLiterals": true
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To completely disable the `quotes` rule, set it to either `0` or `off` in your eslint configuration file (see the different configuration formats [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats)).
Example for disabling in json configuration file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": "off",
     ...
  }
}
```

More on disabling rules can be found [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is coming from react with typescript background you have to use it like below

```
"rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/quotes": "off"
}
```

instead of only using

```
"rules": {
      "quotes": "off"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's prettey obvious you have to write :

"quotes":0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for an entire file, you can add this on top of it:

`/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/quotes */`

and you will no longer get the `ESLint: Strings must use singlequote. (@typescript-eslint/quotes)` warning.